# UrlRewrite & Redirect with an optional /XX/home part in Apache2

Tags: apache, url, redirect, url-rewriting

For a perfect working and Error404-Free log file, I have to redirect all previous (now wrong) home page urls to the new homepage. For that I have a partially working rewrite:

```
RewriteRule ^home$ /en/aster [R=301]
// Works for site.com/home but NOT for site.com/en/home or site.com/xx/home  etc.
```

Q1. How to make an optional part `?????/` sothat  `site.com/anything/home` permanently redirects to `site.com/anything/home`  making sure that the root is not another folder but the actual real sites root followed by the two language chars then /home?

Q2. for consistency and SEO purposes, Do I need a `[R=301]` or a `[R=301,L]` ?

Your ideas and help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure if I completely understand what you want the `site.com/anything/home` to redirect to, but this is how I understood:

`RewriteRule (.*)/home $1/en/aster [R=301,L]`  Will match all requests ending in "/home".  The `(.*)` will keep the urls in the same path.  Therefore `site.com/anything/home` redirects to  `site.com/anything/en/aster`

As far as SEO, there is no difference between `[R=301,L]` and `[R=301]`.  The `L` informs mod_rewrite to not process any further rules, which in this case is what you would want, since you are redirecting to a new page.

Hope this helps.